# Arbitrary Code Execution error on underscore npm package

Tags: npm

[image: terminal picture]

When I run npm install it says found 1596 vulnerabilities (20 low, 51 moderate, 1525 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

When I run npm audit it gives me a list of tables, similar to this:

```
┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ High          │ Arbitrary Code Execution                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ underscore                                                   │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=1.12.1                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @alch/alchemy-web3                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @alch/alchemy-web3 > web3 > web3-shh > web3-net >            │
│               │ web3-core-method > underscore                                │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1674                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Regular Expression Denial of Service                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ hosted-git-info                                              │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.8.9 <3.0.0 || >=3.0.8                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ latest                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ latest > npm > npm-registry-client > normalize-package-data  │
│               │ > hosted-git-info                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/1677                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Remote Memory Exposure                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ request                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=2.68.0                                                     │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ version                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ version > request                                            │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/309                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ ReDoS                                                        │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ brace-expansion                                              │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ >=1.1.7                                                      │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ latest                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ latest > npm > fs-vacuum > rimraf > glob > minimatch >       │
│               │ brace-expansion                                              │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/338                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Moderate      │ Prototype Pollution                                          │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ hoek                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ > 4.2.0 < 5.0.0 || >= 5.0.3                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ latest                                                       │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ latest > npm > node-gyp > request > hawk > hoek              │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/566                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

┌───────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Low           │ Insecure Credential Storage                                  │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Package       │ web3                                                         │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Patched in    │ No patch available                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Dependency of │ @alch/alchemy-web3                                           │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Path          │ @alch/alchemy-web3 > web3                                    │
├───────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ More info     │ https://npmjs.com/advisories/877                             │
└───────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: Follow the remediation mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1674)

Comment: I tried the same but still getting the Arbitrary Code Execution vulnerability. Any other solution?

but I have dependency on loopback instead of  @alch/alchemy-web3

Comment: I removed the package-lock and manually changed the dependencies in the package.json file and then hit-- npm install --. Don't know if this is the right way or not but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had raised this to Alchemy as their @alch/alchemy-web3 latest package dependency was not upgraded to use the patched version of "Underscore".

They did a quick upgrade and it's fixed now as of 7 hours ago at `@alch/alchemy-web3` on version `"^1.0,3"`;

Please run `npm update @alch/alchemy-web3`